# How to (or should you) avoid long methods/classes in jsf

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsf, backing-beans

I'm mostly working with legacy code in a JSF based project and there are lots of quite long classes and methods in backing beans.

This is constantly bugging me but when I look for what can be done, most of the time all I can come up is to divide a long method to n small methods. Which gives you still a very long class and sometimes harder to read too.

So what do you do to keep your backing beans short and concise? Or do you keep one big backing bean for one page? Are there any best-practices?

I assume this is not directly related to jsf but to any model where you are 'backing' up your view with a controller. So a general advise would be helpful also.

Comment: Similar (but not duplicate) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746047/jsf-backing-bean-structure-best-practices

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put all fields in its own class, also called an entity or DTO class (e.g. `User`, `Product`, `Order`, etc) and reference it instead. Those can be JDBC/JPA entities. Put all business methods in its own class, also called a service or domain object (e.g. `UserService`, `ProductService`, etc) and reference it instead. Those can be EJB's.

E.g. thus not

```
public class Bean {

    private Long id;
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
    // Etc... All model fields.

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // >20 lines of business/domain code to prefill the fields from DB.
    }

    public void save() {
        // >20 lines of business/domain code to save the fields in DB.
    }

    // Getters/setters for all fields and possibly also all nested fields.
}
```

But more so

```
public class Bean {

    private Long id;
    private Entity entity;

    @EJB
    private EntityService service;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        entity = service.find(id);
    }

    public void save() {
        service.save(entity);
    }

    // Getter/setter for id and getter for entity.
}
```

Further, I've also seen code wherein the nested objects/entities are delegated through by additional getters/setters in the bean like so

```
private Entity entity;

public String getField1() {
    return entity.getField1();
}

public void setField1(String field1) {
    entity.setField1(field1);
}

// Etc...
```

This is totally unnecessary. Just a single getter for the entity is sufficient (setter is not mandatory!), in combination with

```html
<h:inputText value="#{bean.entity.field1}" />
```

The entities at its own can also be further divided. E.g. `street`, `houseNumber`, `zipCode`, `city`, `country` of an `User` could be replaced by another entity/DTO `Address` within the same `User`.

---

If you have bad luck, the code has been autogenerated by a visual editor (e.g. Netbeans + Woodstock). There's not much to refactor anyway without completely redesigning it, I would rather look for another project.

Comment: Unfortunatly we have none of these :) We use DTO's and service layer, the code is not auto-generated, but has seen lots of changes by lots of developpers. How about dividing independent parts of the view to `<ui:includes/>` and assigning their own beans? Does it become harder to maintain in time?

Comment: You should use one bean per `<h:form>`. You could use `<ui:include>` to overcome section/field repetition (e.g. combo of 2 fields, label+input+message, etc). You could use `<ui:insert>`/`<ui:define>` to overcome template repetition (e.g. header/menu/footer).

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, each method should be 1 step, if that 1 step conatins multiple inner steps you should break them down into smaller methods so its easier to read. The good thing with modern IDE's is that they refractor code for you without much effort at all.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing it, but it helps very little to improve the general structure.

Comment: Well 1 other thing i forget to mention if you ever need to call a certain step you can without having extra code to execute. and especially with eclipse "outline" tab its very easy to navigate. What exactly don't you like about the structure btw??

Comment: Well it's just too long. In general around 800-1000 lines of code (without getters & setters). I consider dividing independent parts of the view with `<ui:include/>`'s. How does it sound? To much trouble?

Answer (score 1):

Not only applicable to backing beans, but to all objects in general:

you should always refactor [long methods](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/long-method) by [extracting](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/extract-method) them into multiple smaller ones.

Comment: Of course, and as I've specified in my question, that's the only thing I do to improve the code quality, but I wonder if there are more specific ways for backing beans or jsf, maybe some features of the framework?