# how can inputText disabled using old data entry?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I click on "Add Invoice" button then open dialog box.
fill some data and save it in database table.
When I click on "Add Invoice" button second time primefaces inputText value is old data and inputText disable at that time.
But following code does not working properly. 
Always inputText blank with disable true ...
Please help me. Thanks

```
<p:dataTable id="invoiceTable" var="invoiceProductsServicesDetail"
    value="#{invoiceBean.invoiceProductsServicesDetails}" border="1"
    editable="true">
    <p:column headerText="Sr. No.">
        <p:outputLabel
            value="#{invoiceProductsServicesDetail.serialNumber}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="HSN Code">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{invoiceProductsServicesDetail.hsnCode}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Quantity">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{invoiceProductsServicesDetail.quantity}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Rate">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{invoiceProductsServicesDetail.rate}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Percentage Discount">
            <p:outputLabel
                value="#{invoiceProductsServicesDetail.percentDiscount}" />
        </p:column>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton value="Add Invoice" type="button"
                onclick="PF('addInvoice').show();" />
        </f:facet>
 </p:dataTable>
```

Following Dialoag box open when click on "Add Invoice" Button. And it get input.

```
<p:dialog id="invoiceDialog" header="Add Invoice"
    widgetVar="addInvoice" minHeight="40" showEffect="explode"
    hideEffect="fold">
    <table border="1" id="dialogTable">
        <tr>
            <td><p:outputLabel value="HSN Code" /></td>
            <td><p:outputLabel value="Quantity" /></td>
            <td><p:outputLabel value="Rate" /></td>
            <td><p:outputLabel value="Percentage Discount" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p:inputText value="#{invoiceBean.hsnCode}" size="6"
                disabled="#{invoiceBean.hsnCode != null}" /></td>
            <td><p:inputText id="quaintity"
                value="#{invoiceBean.quantity}" size="3" styleClass="Alingment"
                required="true" label="Quantity"
                requiredMessage="Quantity Require Entry" autocomplete="off"
                disabled="#{invoiceBean.quantity != 0}" /></td>
            <td><p:inputText id="rate" value="#{invoiceBean.rate}"
                styleClass="Alingment" required="true" label="Rate"
                requiredMessage="Rate Require Entry" autocomplete="off"
                disabled="#{invoiceBean.rate != 0}" /></td>
            <td><p:inputText value="#{invoiceBean.percentDiscount}"
                size="2" styleClass="Alingment" autocomplete="off"
                disabled="#{invoiceBean.percentDiscount != 0}" /></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <p:commandButton value="Save New Invoice"
        action="#{invoiceBean.addRow}" update=":form:invoiceTable growl"
        process="@form invoiceTable" onclick="PF('addInvoice').hide();">
        <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are You Sure ?"
                    icon="ui-icon-alert" />
        <f:ajax render=":form:invoiceTable" />
    </p:commandButton>
</p:dialog>
```

Manage Bean : invoiceBean
Here, I following method is used to store data in specific object.

```
public void addRow() {
    int lastBalance, currentBalance, storeBalance;
    transaction = new Transaction();
    invoiceProductsServicesDetail = new InvoiceProductsServicesDetail();
    invoiceDao = new InvoiceDao();
    transactionDao = new TransactionDao();
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) facesContext.getViewRoot()
            .findComponent("form:invoiceTable");
    UIComponent uiTable = ComponentUtils.findParentForm(facesContext,
            dataTable);
    final AjaxBehavior behavior = new AjaxBehavior();
    try {
        if (descriptionOfGoodsOrService != ""
                && descriptionOfGoodsOrService != null && rate != 0
                && quantity != 0) {
            amount = (rate * quantity);
            this.grossTotal = amount = (amount - (amount * (percentDiscount / 100)));
            this.netTotal = ((amount) + (amount * (Constants.VAT / 100)) + (amount * (Constants.SERVICE_TAX / 100)));

            if (chequeAmount <= amount) {
                invoiceProductsServicesDetails = invoiceDao.getInvoiceProductsServicesDetailData(invoices.get(
                        0).getId());

                transactions = transactionDao.getTransactions(invoices.get(
                        0).getId());
                invoiceProductsServicesDetail.setSerialNumber(dataTable
                        .getRowCount() + 1);
                invoiceProductsServicesDetail.setHsnCode(hsnCode);
                invoiceProductsServicesDetail
                        .setPercentDiscount(percentDiscount);
                invoiceProductsServicesDetail.setQuantity(quantity);
                invoiceProductsServicesDetail.setRate(rate);
                invoiceProductsServicesDetail.setInvoiceId(invoices.get(0)
                        .getId());

                invoiceProductsServicesDetails
                        .add(invoiceProductsServicesDetail);

                if (transactions.size() != 0) {
                    setTransactions(transactions);
                    lastBalance = transactions.get(transactions.size() - 1)
                            .getBalance();
                } else {
                    lastBalance = 0;
                }
                currentBalance = amount - chequeAmount;
                storeBalance = lastBalance + currentBalance;

                transaction.setModeOfPayment(modeOfPayment);
                if (modeOfPayment.equals("Cheque")) {
                    transaction.setBankName(bankName);
                    transaction.setChequeNumber(chequeNumber);
                    transaction.setBalance(storeBalance);
                } else {

                    transaction.setBalance(storeBalance);

                }
                transaction.setChequeAmount(chequeAmount);
                transaction.setReceiptNumber(String.valueOf(new Date()
                        .getTime()));
                transactionDao.setTransaction(transaction, invoices.get(0).getId());
                this.transactions = transactionDao.getTransactions(invoices.get(0).getId());
                invoiceDao.insertInvoiceProductsServicesDetail(invoiceProductsServicesDetail);
                RowEditEvent rowEditEvent = new RowEditEvent(uiTable,behavior, invoiceProductsServicesDetail);
                rowEditEvent.setPhaseId(PhaseId.UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES);
                dataTable.broadcast(rowEditEvent);
            } else {

                FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(
                        FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "System Error",
                        "Your Enter Amout Is Must Less Then Total Amount");
                facesContext.addMessage(null, message);
            }

        }
    } catch (AbortProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        invoiceProductsServicesDetail = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not clearing out the dialog before opening it.

Change

```
<p:commandButton value="Add Invoice" type="button"
    onclick="PF('addInvoice').show();" />
```

To

```
<p:commandButton value="Add Invoice" type="button"
    action="#{invoiceBean.createInvoice}" update="invoiceDialog"
    oncomplete="PF('addInvoice').show();" />
```

With

```
public void createInvoice() {
    hsnCode = null;
    quantity = null;
    rate = null;
    percentDiscount = null;
}
```

---

That said, the design of your model is broken. You're flattening and repeating the model's properties straight in the backing bean instead of using the model directly. Fix it by **removing** the `hsnCode`, `quantity`, `rate` and `percentDiscount` properties and then adding this:

```
private InvoiceProductsServicesDetail invoiceProductsServicesDetail;

public void createInvoice() {
    invoiceProductsServicesDetail = new InvoiceProductsServicesDetail();
}
```

With

```
<p:inputText value="#{invoiceBean.invoiceProductsServicesDetail.hsnCode}" ... />
<p:inputText value="#{invoiceBean.invoiceProductsServicesDetail.quantity}" ... />
...
```

#### See also:

- [Creating master-detail pages for entities, how to link them and which bean scope to choose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459903/correct-usage-of-session-scope-in-two-page-master-detail-user-interface/)
- [Passing a JSF2 managed pojo bean into EJB or putting what is required into a transfer object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246141/passing-a-jsf2-managed-pojo-bean-into-ejb-or-putting-what-is-required-into-a-tra/)
- [How to (or should you) avoid long methods/classes in jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412547/how-to-or-should-you-avoid-long-methods-classes-in-jsf/)