# Making Distinctions Between Different Kinds of JSF Managed-Beans

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, backing-beans

I recently read this article from Neil Griffin [Making Distinctions Between Different Kinds of JSF Managed-Beans](http://java.dzone.com/articles/making-distinctions-between) and it got me thinking about the distinction between different beans in my own application. To quickly summarise the gist:

> - Model Managed-Bean: This type of managed-bean participates in the
>     "Model" concern of the MVC design pattern. When you see the word
>     "model" -- think DATA. A JSF model-bean should be a POJO that follows
>     the JavaBean design pattern with getters/setters encapsulating
>     properties.
> - Backing Managed-Bean: This type of managed-bean participates in the
>     "View" concern of the MVC design pattern. The purpose of a
>     backing-bean is to support UI logic, and has a 1::1 relationship with
>     a JSF view, or a JSF form in a Facelet composition. Although it
>     typically has JavaBean-style properties with associated
>     getters/setters, these are properties of the View -- not of the
>     underlying application data model. JSF backing-beans may also have JSF
>     actionListener and valueChangeListener methods.
> - Controller Managed-Bean: This type of managed-bean participates in
>     the "Controller" concern of the MVC design pattern. The purpose of a
>     controller bean is to execute some kind of business logic and return a
>     navigation outcome to the JSF navigation-handler. JSF controller-beans
>     typically have JSF action methods (and not actionListener methods).
> - Support Managed-Bean: This type of bean "supports" one or more views
>     in the "View" concern of the MVC design pattern. The typical use case
>     is supplying an ArrayList to JSF h:selectOneMenu drop-down
>     lists that appear in more than one JSF view. If the data in the
>     dropdown lists is particular to the user, then the bean would be kept
>     in session scope.
> - Utility Managed-Bean: This type of bean provides some type of
>     "utility" function to one or more JSF views. A good example of this
>     might be a FileUpload bean that can be reused in multiple web
>     applications.

This made sense to me and for the past few hours I have been refactoring my code and came up with the following with respect to the user login:

The `AuthenticationController` is an example of a Controller Managed-Bean. It is request-scoped and features two getters and setters for setting a username and password, and two navigation methods, `authenticate` and `logout`, navigating the user to either their private area upon successful login, or back to the main page when logging out.

The `UserBean` is an example of a Support Managed-Bean. It is session-scoped and features an instance of `User` class (which would be null when you are not authenticated) with a getter and setter, nothing more.

The `AuthenticationController` has this user as a managed property (`@ManagedProperty(value = "#{userController.user} private User user;`). Upon successful authentication, the `AuthenticationController` would set the managed property to the actual user instance with the corresponding username that was used for the login.

Any new beans would be able to grab the user as a managed property as well and pull the data they need, such as group membership for instance, if the `User` class would feature a list with group names.

Would this way be the proper way to go about with regard to the seperation of concerns?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This is a very subjective question. I personally disagree that article and find that it's giving really bad advice to starters.

---

> *Model Managed-Bean: This type of managed-bean participates in the "Model" concern of the MVC design pattern. When you see the word "model" -- think DATA. A JSF model-bean should be a POJO that follows the JavaBean design pattern with getters/setters encapsulating properties.*

I would absolutely not make or call it a managed bean. Just make it a property of a `@ManagedBean`. For example a DTO or JPA `@Entity`.

---

> *Backing Managed-Bean: This type of managed-bean participates in the "View" concern of the MVC design pattern. The purpose of a backing-bean is to support UI logic, and has a 1::1 relationship with a JSF view, or a JSF form in a Facelet composition. Although it typically has JavaBean-style properties with associated getters/setters, these are properties of the View -- not of the underlying application data model. JSF backing-beans may also have JSF actionListener and valueChangeListener methods.*

This way you keep duplicating and mapping the properties of the entity in the managed bean. This makes no sense to me. As said, just make the entity a property of the managed bean and let the input fields refer it directly like `#{authenticator.user.name}` instead of `#{authenticator.username}`.

---

> *Controller Managed-Bean: This type of managed-bean participates in the "Controller" concern of the MVC design pattern. The purpose of a controller bean is to execute some kind of business logic and return a navigation outcome to the JSF navigation-handler. JSF controller-beans typically have JSF action methods (and not actionListener methods).*

This describes the `@RequestScoped`/`@ViewScoped` `@ManagedBean` class pretty much. Whether event listener methods are allowed or not depends on whether they are specific to the view which is tied to the bean and/or are for their job dependent on the bean's state. If they are, then they belongs in the bean. If not, then they should be a standalone implementation of any [`FacesListener` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/event/FacesListener.html), but definitely not a managed bean.

---

> *Support Managed-Bean: This type of bean "supports" one or more views in the "View" concern of the MVC design pattern. The typical use case is supplying an ArrayList to JSF h:selectOneMenu drop-down lists that appear in more than one JSF view. If the data in the dropdown lists is particular to the user, then the bean would be kept in session scope.*

Fine. For application wide data like dropdown lists just use an `@ApplicationScoped` bean and for session wide data like logged-in user and its preferences just use a `@SessionScoped` one.

---

> *Utility Managed-Bean: This type of bean provides some type of "utility" function to one or more JSF views. A good example of this might be a FileUpload bean that can be reused in multiple web applications.*

This makes not really sense to me. Backing beans are usually tied to single views. This sounds too much like an [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/event/ActionListener.html) implementation which is to be used by `<f:actionListener>` in command components to your choice. Definitely not a managed bean.

For kickoff examples of the right approach, see also:

- [Hello World example in Our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)
- ["Bookstore CRUD" example in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526267/javax-persistence-transactionrequiredexception-in-small-facelet-application/16542568#16542568)
- ["Master-detail" example in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459903/creating-master-detail-pages-for-entities-how-to-link-them-and-which-bean-scope/8464636#8464636)
- [JSF Service Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011392/jsf-service-layer)
- [Communication in JSF 2](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html)

Comment: Thanks BalusC! I guess I need to get it out of my head that there are strict rules to organising a project a certain way and be more pragmatic instead of getting hung up on such articles, forcing myself to adhere.

Comment: +1 I cannot upvote this answer enough! I read a hundred times that same article, and spent some amount of time trying to follow its advice, until I gave up cause it wasn't making sense to me duplicating so many things...

Comment: Thanks BalusC. Initially the article made sense, because I am new to JSF, but after playing around with my beans, your update makes much more sense.

Comment: We fall in this question today, @BalusC, and I found your answer while I was googling for an explanation. I do not agree with the article's point, but I actually can't understand yours. IMHO, ManagedBeans are in somewhere between View and Model, while FacesServlet is the Controller. But I'm curious to know your opinion.