# JSF Unable to create managed bean X using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf, javabeans

I'm using Eclipse Indigo. I'm following a patter from [this](http://blog.icesoft.org/blojsom/blog/default/2009/04/23/Making-distinctions-between-different-kinds-of-JSF-managed-beans/) site where it separates the beans in 5 classes, I'm using `ModelBean`, `BackingBean` and `ControllerBean`.

My project structure is:

`Java resources` -> `src` -> `com.erp3.gui.user` with those beans mentioned above

Here is my **UserController**

```
package com.erp3.gui.user;

import java.io.Serializable;

import com.erp3.bo.user.UserBO;

public class UserController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private UserBO bo;
    private UserModel model;

    public UserController() {
        bo = new UserBO();
        model = new UserModel();
    }

    public void Login() {
        model.setVo(bo.executeLogin(model.getVo()));
        System.out.println("Foi");
    }

    public UserBO getBo() {
        return bo;
    }

    public void setBo(UserBO bo) {
        this.bo = bo;
    }

    public UserModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(UserModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }   
}
```

When I run the `index.html`:

```
<h:inputText label="Usuário" id="username" value="#{userController.model.vo.login}"/>
```

And I have this exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to create managed bean userController.  The following problems were found:
     - Bean or property class com.erp3.gui.user.UserController for managed bean userController cannot be found.
     - Bean or property class com.erp3.gui.user.UserController for managed bean userController cannot be found.
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:321)
```

I was told that Eclipse doesn't work with annotation, so I have my `faces-config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
 <managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>userController</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.erp3.gui.user.UserController</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
 </managed-bean>
 <managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>userBacking</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.erp3.gui.user.UserBacking</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
 </managed-bean>
 <managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>userModel</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.erp3.gui.user.UserModel</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
 </managed-bean>
 <application>
  <message-bundle>com.erp3.gui.helpers.messages</message-bundle>
 </application>
</faces-config>
```

*If necessary, I can add my other beans, didn't do because would make a enormous question*

**EDIT**

I have added the annotations on my beans and the problem changed to:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /views/user/login.xhtml @18,135 value="#{userController.model.vo.login}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'userController' resolved to null
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:97)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:91)
    javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1023)
    javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:953)
    javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1204)
    javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:693)
    javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:240)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1081)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1081)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1159)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:72)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
```

But when I add the beans to the `faces-config` the error comes back.

Comment: *"I was told that Eclipse doesn't work with annotation"* either that person is lying, or you misinterpreted him/her. By the way I disagree that ICEfaces article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223055/distinction-between-different-types-of-managed-beans

Comment: @BalusC I heard that ten minutes ago from a friend, I'm gonna update him =)

Comment: Is it necessary to have JBoos Tools on my Eclipse to work with `xhtml`files? This friend told me that but now I'm starting to doubt his words

Comment: @BalusC thanks for the link, I'm gonna follow your answer but I need to find a solution for this not working bean, any ideas?

Comment: "Necessary" is a big word. You can do it without JBoss Tools, but you'll miss autocompletion, wizards, generators and that kind of helpful stuff related to JSF/Facelets/EL. So you'd have to do everything "by hand". Heck, Eclipse is even not necessary. You can go away with Notepad and `javac`. But that's a lot of work :)

Comment: its not necessary, but JBoss Tools helps a lot during development. But you can do fine without it.

Comment: but the autocompletion is a good friend, especially for a beginner

Comment: maybe this problem is related with the IceFaces pattern?

Comment: any ideas? I'm looking for a solution for hours

Comment: plz..any advises? I'm desperate for a solution here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately it was a tremendous lack of attention.

On my project Build Path I was referencing to jars on my server and another programmer changed those jars addresses so I had broken references.

The weird is that Eclipse haven't send any alert about this issue.

Problem solved.

Thanks BalusC and Montolide for your time and attention.

Comment: I had the same problem (and resolution). The reported message is a bit of a red herring and should probably be improved on in the future, in my humble opinion.

Comment: I had the same 'Unable to create managed bean' com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException.  My case also was related to the build path. In Eclipse -> Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export I had changed the Build class path order.  Changing back to 1. JRE, 2. Source files 3. Maven dependencies, 4. JSF library, 5. Apache Tomcat resolved the problem.  Agree with http://stackoverflow.com/users/1399438/stockb, the error message could be better composed.

Comment: @StockB I agree, feel free to update the question ;)

Comment: I think the question is an accurate representation of the problem and shouldn't be edited. However, I think that ICEfaces' error message is a red herring and should be improved. If it hasn't been changed yet (two years later), feel free to update ICEfaces source because it's under the Apache 2 license. :)

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse works fine with annotations (or maybe its JBoss tools?), so you should use `@ManagedBean` on your class.

Are your `faces-config` on WEB-INF folder?

Comment: I'm using JBoos, shouldn't? And yes, `faces-config` on WEB-INF. I have added JBoos to add support for `xhtml` files, is it necessary? It's my first project

Comment: any ideas? I'm looking for a solution for hours