# Best Practice In JSF for Forms, Datatables, etc

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, managed-bean

Should I have a bean for every form, datatable etc in JSF?

For example, I have a form for registration, which simply has 2 fields and a button which are:
**nickname, password, submit**

Should submitting this form go to a RegistirationFormBean or somewhere in UserBean or UserServiceBean?

What is the best practice?

Thank you.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7223055/1065197

Comment: Do you want to implement a login feature using JSF and handle the authentication throughout the application run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To decide whether or not you should create a `@ManagedBean` exclusively for a component of the page (e.g. form, datatable), I believe you should think about the **`modularity`** of your design.

The 1st question you should ask yourself is: `Will the component be re-used in many pages?`. For example, on sensitive pages such as `ChangePassword` or `DeleteAccount`, usually, you will ask the user to enter the current password to validate his identity before performing any logic. In this case, you should definitely have an exclusive bean for the validating password component so that you can re-use the component again and again without having to re-code the validating function every time.

Secondly, I usually use `@ManagedBean` as a place to hold all the **related** functions that work **toward the same goal**. This grouping of functions can be pretty subjective. For example, I can have a page called `CreateProduct.xhtml` with a bean called `CreateProductBean` that has all the functions for creating a product. In this case, it's like `1 bean per view`. Another way is to have a bean called `ProductManager` that has functions for everything related to the `Product` object (i.e. create, read, update, remove). In this case, it's like `1 bean for many views` (e.g. `CreateProduct.xhtml`, `RemoveProduct.xhtml`). For ease of future maintenance and division of work, I usually use `1 bean per view`. The 2nd approach `1 bean for many views` is also good on certain situations but I suddenly cannot think of an example yet :P... I will update my answer when I got a good one ;).

Thirdly, I prefer to follow the 3-tier MVC model and separate back-end logic away from the front-end. For example, to persist a new account in the database, I will inject an `@EJB` or a `@WebServiceRef` to ask the back-end system to perform the necessary logic. It's definitely more maintenance friendly in the future :).

So, using your `RegisterAccount` example, I will have

- 1 bean called `UserExistenceValidator` to check if a `nickname` exists in the database. During registration, I can throw an error if the user chooses a `nickname` that is taken. I can also use this bean to check if a user exists in the `AddFriend.xhtml` page.
- Another bean called `RegistirationFormBean` to capture a user's inputs and talk to the back-end to persist the new account.

Comment: CreateProductBean and ProductManager bean are then both of requestscoped?

Comment: @KorayTugay: `@Scope` is another story :P... `CreateProductBean` should definitely be `@RequestScoped`. However, as for `ProductManager`, you may need to have a property called `List<Product>` to help display products for updating, removing, etc. In these situations, most of the time, I use `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: All this is explained in the link I've posted as related on OP's question. BalusC even explains the different *kinds* of managed beans and their respective scope...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Sorry, I don't see BalusC's explanation has anything to do with my answer :). Even BalusC's answer is related to the OP's question in some sense, my answer is more to the point of what I myself think is important in deciding the design of an application.

Answer (score 2):

Its actually a pretty interesting topic to tweak any `JSF` lover's brain, so I could not resist myself and I would like to go with detail explanation.

> One of the very interesting and significant cause behind the invention of `JSF` was, wiring client side event to server side application code like any swing application and getting rid of handing of request and response object explicitly. Like any swing application, we can now simply bind any client side event (say, button click) with some server side code to handle that event, without worrying the facts and complexities of writing an web application.

As a result when designing any web apps, that uses JSF, the designer can focus on the user experience as easily as designing an event driven swing application. So as the consequence, you design the view pages and identify the events to do tasks and navigate between the views. Finally you write some server side codes to be executed in those events, to do the job you want. Those server side codes reside in your managed beans.

If we classify based on the type responsibility, there are several types of managed beans:

- Model Managed-Bean
- Backing Managed-Bean
- Controller Managed-Bean
- Support Managed-Bean
- Utility Managed-Bean

You will find the details of each of the type in [this article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/making-distinctions-between).

Your problem is, how to distribute the responsibilities of `Controller Managed-Bean`. There are several issues to consider, while you are distributing this kind of responsibilities:

1. The complexity of the task to do.
2. Re-usability of it.
3. Modularity in terms of responsibility (type of jobs to do).
4. Modularity in terms of business perspective.
5. Decoupling the responsibilities. etc.

You can design your system to with a single `controller` for all the views of your simple **CURD** operations of a `model`. But if you need to handle multiple complex transactions in your single `create` operation, then separating the operations to multiple `controllers`, would be a better design. Though your registration procedure is pretty much simple, you should use a separate `controller` to handle the task. Because it will not be a good idea, to put any task in the same managed bean, that is not simple and related enough to reside with the task "registration".  I think this, concludes your query!

Answer (score 0):

you should a data transfer object bean and a domain bean for ui submission and for persistence in db respectively.
using a controller class, process your ui jsf submission data and create a clean domain bean and use this to persist.

the best practice should always de-couple processes/entities if possible.
also your dto bean might have accessory and more data than your domain bean which u might require for several purposes.

Answer (score 0):

In similar situations, I always have a `UserManagedBean` that handles user relative operations, such as login, registration, change password, etc...
To deal with these operations, I put an attribute in the `UserManagedBean` of type `User` (or whatever class name) which corresponds to the persisted data related to users (usually in DB table user).
In your case `nickname` and `password` are attributes of the `User` class.  As for the `submit` it will invoke a method in the `UserManagedBean` to authenticate user:

```
<h:inputText value="#{userManagedBean.user.nickname}"/>
<h:inputSecret value="#{userManagedBean.user.password}"/>
<h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{userManagedBean.loginUser}"/>
```

Of course, the `loginUser` method will invoke a call to the service layer which will invoke DAO layer to check credentials against DB (or other storage).
If the login is successful, the user attribute in our managed bean (which should be session scoped) is initialized with returned object from DB.

Comment: Do you also have something like if user in UserManagedBean is not null, then the user is logged in?

Comment: you mean direct redirection ? if yes, then you should use a filter, in which you can implement both the "remember me" function and the redirection when user is already logged in