# JSF Controller Bean - Scoping

Tags: spring, jsf

WI have a question about the "Best Practice" Design for controller beans.

I was reading this very good question and the linking article:

Question "JSF backing bean structure (best practices)"
[Scoping Best Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746047/jsf-backing-bean-structure-best-practices)

Online Article
[Distinctions between different kinds of JSF Managed-beans](http://blog.icefaces.org/blojsom/blog/default/2009/04/23/Making-distinctions-between-different-kinds-of-JSF-managed-beans/)

My question is concerning the controller bean. I'm using JSF / Spring and was wondering why I would want to use request scope for Controller beans?

The controller logic being  defined as "...execute some kind of business logic and return navigation outcome.." I would think doesn't require a request scope but either session/application scope. Why keep creating those controller objects on every request?

In my case I would create the controller bean in the faces-config obviously and inject it with my managed properties through spring.

Thoughts please around the scoping? Thanks.

Clarification:
Using JSF 1.2, Spring 3. Using faces-config.xml to declare my beans. Not through annotations.

Comment: Related: [Distinction between different types of managed beans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223055/distinction-between-different-types-of-managed-beans)

Comment: Thanks for the additional article BalusC. So if you had a Controller class who purpose was to support business logic, would their be anything wrong you think in making that application scope?

Comment: If the controller contains a model representing request/session scoped data, then definitely yes. It would clash in multiple requests/sessions.

Comment: Ok but if the controller was more like a static class that performed the business logic but didn't need a modal as a instance variable in it, it would be fine.

Comment: That should then not be a `@ManagedBean`, but a `@Stateless` EJB  (or whatever Spring offers to supplant EJB, I don't do Spring, so I can't go in detail) which you inject in your real `@ManagedBean`.

Comment: really, an EJB. Interesting. Why is that?

Comment: Nevermind this. I forgot that you're using Spring. Read "Spring controller" instead of EJB.

Comment: Just added a edit at the end to clairfy what I am using.