# How many views should a backing bean belong to?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I just read through this question: [JSF backing bean structure (best practices)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746047/jsf-backing-bean-structure-best-practices) and I am trying to understand when I should make a new backing bean in my application. If I have a view with registering a question should I then have a backing bean for that task, and another one backing bean for the editing of a question, and a third one for the view where I list all the questions and so on? Or, should these three views have a common backing bean?

And if I have a view and a backing bean for adding a question on the admin side, can I use the same backing bean for adding a question on the user side which has its own view since they both will do the same task?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223055/distinction-between-different-types-of-managed-beans That article is quoted so many times here.

Comment: @Hyperion it all depends (and always) depends on the application. Try to use "loose coupling" whenever possible and minimize the scope of the beans (ViewScope/RequestScope). There's no right and wrong, but once you start managing states you open the door for subtle bugs. Generally, if it makes sense in the model: do it. [This is simply my opinion, I backed myself into a corner a lot early in learning JSF and reducing scope/ordering my model made maintenance easier]

Answer (score 1):

Recognize that you can have combinations of extension and composition.  I always try to have one backing bean per page.  If there are common elements on multiple pages, I'd factor those out into a common utility bean - and then have that utility bean as a member of the backing beans for each page that needs it.