# Why @Model is @RequestScope not @SessionScope or @ViewScope?

Tags: jsf, cdi, jsf-2.3

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1030196/4649524) on [JSF backing bean structure (best practices)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746047/jsf-backing-bean-structure-best-practices)
 and [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/making-distinctions-between) about the same subject and I'm really confused.

In the answer and the article, model-beans are session scoped but the `javax.enterprise.inject.Model @Model` annotation is request scoped.

In the documentaion it says:

> The built-in stereotype intended for use with beans that define the
>   model layer of an MVC web application architecture such as JSF.

I see this as a contradiction.

What is the real use of `@Model` and why it's `@RequestScoped`? what should I use for model-beans and is the referenced answer still apply?

Comment: Please read the comments over there as well, you would have found among others https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223055

Comment: @BalusC really resourceful answer, thank you.